# Seleccionar grupo de sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de seleccionar un grupo de la SQL y mostrar el grupo no los productos, ejemplo

SQL:

```
ID   Categoria  Descricion
1    cate 1      xxxx
2    cate 1      xxxx
3    cate 1      xxxx
4    cate 1      xxxx 
5    cate 2      xxxx
6    cate 2      xxxx
7    cate 2      xxxx
8    cate 2      xxxx
```

La idea es mostrar los grupos...

INDEX

cate1   cate2

y no que salgan todos los productos que contiene en "cate1" y "cate2"

Esto para poder hacer un acceso a una pagina que dentro de cada categoría tiene unos 50 prods

Dejo las líneas con las que tomo y muestro los productos dentro de las categorías

```
<?php
    $sentencia = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE categoria ");
    $productos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
```

Con esto logro tomar todos los productos dentro de "categoria" no e logrado tomar la "categoria" "DDD" y mostrarla como tal

Dejo una imagen de lo que quiero hacer...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto esta hecho manualmente para cada categoría, este seria el código

```
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            <a href="CUI" class="cta-btn">
                <div class="shop">
                    <div class="shop-img">
                        <img src="../../img/Cat/SubCat/Conexiones/CUI.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="shop-body">
                        <h3>VER<br>INOXIDABLE</h3>
                        ACCEDER A LOS PRODUCTOS <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /shop -->
```

Comment: y group by no te funciono? o select distinct?

Comment: No, me tira error de "PDOException SQLSTATE"

Comment: Y si pones eso? porque se hace asi como te dije...

Comment: Es cuando me tira ese error

Comment: A ver partamos del punto, soy muy nuevo en esto, dejo el código de como esta ahora que tira el error

<?php
            $sentencia = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM Productos DISTINCT CRE ");
            $productos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
        ?>

Comment: Select categoría from productos group by categoría, así de simple

Comment: Prueba con `SELECT distinct categoria FROM Productos`

Comment: claro.. ese select que escribiste esta mal.. el distinct no va ahi... ahi te dieron dos soluciones simples de como hacer esto, pero te recomendaria leer sobre sql de forma urgente, porque te vas a trabar en cosas igual de simples siempre....